# My client program won't connect to my server program

Tags: c#, tcpclient, tcplistener

I want to create a client and server program that will send object between eachother and make it work so that the two programs can communicate over two seperate host system.

Running both of the programs on the same host system makes it work, but when I try running the server program and client program on two diffrent systems I just get a timeout error on the client side. There have been one odd case where it actually worked by having the server run on my PC and the client on my work laptop. However, when trying to connect to the server using another laptop it didn't work. It won't work either when I have the server on my laptop and the client on my PC.

Server code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
namespace Controller
{
    //Class for handeling induvidual clients seperatly
    class ClientHandler 

    {
        static LinkedList<ClientHandler> allClients = new LinkedList<ClientHandler>(); //List of client handlers
        static int nextNo = 0;

        //lock used on client handler list when adding a new client handler 
        private readonly object synLock = new object();

        TcpClient MyClient; 
        string MyName; 
        NetworkStream MyStream; 

        public ClientHandler(TcpClient clientInfo)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("ClientHandler created");

            //client object for the handler
            this.MyClient = clientInfo;
            //Name of the clienthandler (to differentiate them from eachother)
            this.MyName = "Client" + nextNo.ToString();
            //Gets the stream for the client
            this.MyStream = MyClient.GetStream(); 



            //Make sure that only one thread can add clienthandler to list at a time
            lock (synLock) 
            {
                allClients.AddLast(this);
                nextNo++;

            }

            Thread clientthread = new Thread(listenandsend);
            clientthread.Start();

        }

        //Thread for reading what clients sends over stream
        public void listenandsend()  
        {
            while (true)
            {   //Buffer for recieving data
                byte[] recievedBuffer = new byte[1000]; 

                //Places data it gets from the client into the buffer
                MyStream.Read(recievedBuffer, 0, recievedBuffer.Length);

                //transform byte array to object of contest class (ref divingClassLibrary)
                divingClassLibrary.Contest c = divingClassLibrary.Contest.fromByte(recievedBuffer); 

                //Test to see if it got the right object
                Console.WriteLine("CONTEST NAME: " + c.name + ", CONTEST DATE: " + c.date);
            }
        }
    }



    class ControllerProgram
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            //-------  --This section is used for printing out the servers own ip address---------
            string serverIP = "";

            IPAddress[] localIP = Dns.GetHostAddresses(Dns.GetHostName());

            foreach (IPAddress address in localIP)
            {
                if (address.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
                {
                    serverIP = address.ToString();
                }
            }

            Console.WriteLine(serverIP);
            //--------------------------------------------------------------------------------



            //Creates a listner for the server
            TcpListener serverListner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), 8080); 
            TcpClient client = default(TcpClient);



            //----------------trys-catch for starting listener-----------------
            try
            {
                serverListner.Start();
                Console.WriteLine("Server started...");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.Read();

            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------




            //----------------Loop for listening for clients-------------------
            while (true)
            {
                client = serverListner.AcceptTcpClient();
                Console.WriteLine("Found a clients");

                ClientHandler handle = new ClientHandler(client);

            }
            //----------------------------------------------------------------


        }


    }
}
```

Client code:

```
using System;
using System.Text;

using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace ClientProgram
{
    class client
    {
        static TcpClient serverclient; 
        static NetworkStream MyStream;


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Asks the user for the ip address of the server
            Console.WriteLine("Type in the ip address of server:");
            //Puts the ip address to a string
            string serverIP = Console.ReadLine();

            int port = 8080;

            serverclient = new TcpClient();
            //Creates the endpoint for the client 
            IPEndPoint ipEnd = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), port);

            //--------------Try-catch for connectng to server------------------
            try
            {
                serverclient.Connect(ipEnd);

            }

            catch(Exception ex) {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                Console.Read();
            }
            //-----------------------------------------------------------------


            if (serverclient.Connected)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("I got connected!");

                MyStream = serverclient.GetStream();

                //Starts the thread for listening to the server
                Thread listnerThread = new Thread(listentoserver);
                listnerThread.Start();


                while (true)
                {
                    //Asks he user for the contest name
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Contest name: ");
                    string name = Console.ReadLine();

                    //Asks he user for the contest date
                    Console.WriteLine("Enter Contest date: ");
                    string date = Console.ReadLine();




                    //Creates an byte array by creating the contest object and converting it into bytes
                    byte[] sendData = divingClassLibrary.Contest.toByte(new divingClassLibrary.Contest(0, name, date));

                    //Sends the byte array to the server
                    MyStream.Write(sendData, 0, sendData.Length); 

                    //for ending the connection and the program (will be used later)
                    if (sendData.Equals("bye"))
                    {
                        break;
                    }

                }

                MyStream.Close();
                serverclient.Close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

The Client should connect and start asking for the user to enter the contest's name and then the contest's date, but instead I just get an timeout error.

Comment: I would avoid using 8080 for your TCP port, a lot of services like to reserve that. Try a random high-numbered port. Also make sure that the firewall on both the client and the server allow communications through that port.

Comment: Seconded.  Avoid using standard port numbers.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is in your server code.
This line:

```
TcpListener serverListner = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Parse(serverIP), 8080);
```

says basically that the listener is waiting for 8080, however, your server is not properly in that port, I think that's why when you have both codes (server and client) under the same host work.

Note: If you use a different laptop to connect both you should make sure you have a public IP address.